# SQL Left Join Omit Rows Found

Tags: sql, left-join, rows

I have two tables that one list the transactions and one that list that are cancelled. How do you only show the transactions that are not cancelled and omit the cancelled ones?

[image]

I just want to show the transactions that are not cancelled, in this case the transaction with
transaction_id = 1.

Comment: could you post the sample tables as well as query

Comment: It'd be helpful if you showed us example tables and what you expect

Comment: Please provide some sample data and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE 
WHERE transaction_id
NOT IN (
    SELECT transaction_id 
    FROM CANCELED_TABLE);
```

However, looking at your example I would suggest to add a field "canceled" to TRANSACTION_TABLE instead of using a seperate table.

Comment: Usually OPs simplify their data to the bare essentials needed to show the problem (thanks for that, btw), so adding a "canceled" field to the row instead of a separate table may or may not be a good idea. There could be several aspects of the cancellation the OP simplified away--who requested the cancellation, who authorized the cancellation, any terms (restocking fee, etc.) that may apply and so forth. Or a single cancellation may apply to more than one transaction. Any one of those conditions would trigger 2nf and, thus, a separate table anyway. Barring that though, yes, keep it simple.

Comment: Thats what I tried to say with looking at his example... Sry if it was not that clear @TommCatt

Comment: Sorry? Not at all! A great many problems presented here and at any workplace are created or complicated by a too-elaborate design. For those cases, design simplification is always preferable to a snazzy query, no matter how utterly awesome that query may be. But there are limitations to even the best ideas. The OP should be aware of those. It may well have been the best solution for his situation.

Answer (score 0):

try using left outer join

```
  select * from TRANSACTION_TABLE  trtb left outer join CANCELED_TABLE cntb on trtb.transaction_id=cntb.transaction_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When building a somewhat complex query, the best way is to build it in stages, looking over the results you get at every stage. You know that to see the transactions that have not been canceled a left outer join is needed. Ok then, write it. (See <kbd>SQL Fiddle</kbd> for details):

```
select  *
from    Xaction  x
left join Cancellations c
    on  c.TransID = x.ID;
```

Now look at the results. This gives you all of the transactions and either the details from the Cancellation table, if they exist, or NULLs. The rows you want to see are the ones where the cancellation data is null. So just filter on that condition:

```
select  *
from    Xaction  x
left join Cancellations c
    on  c.TransID = x.ID
where   c.TransID is null;
```

Then just clean up the *select* list to arrange the data to just the way you want to see it. Easy.